# Turning my Pycharm file into an exe Python3.8 [WINDOWS 10]

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, pyinstaller, python-3.8

So recently I've been trying to turn one of the simple programs that I wrote into an exe file. I tried using pyinstaller but the exe just opens and closes quickly flashing a cmd onto my screen but nothing like what the program was supposed to do.

Also, I cannot use the cmd to run python files. For example, I took the same Pycharm file I was trying to turn into an exe and while the cmd was in the directory with the pycharm file I typed 
`python *MyScript*.py` and it returns: *'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Any help would be amazing.

My Code is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://classroom.google.com/u/0/h')

    email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
    email.send_keys('Email')

    next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]')
    next_button.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    password.send_keys('Password')

    next2_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/span')
    next2_button.click()

    driver.maximize_window()

main()
```

I am just opening my cmd as an administrator (I've tried as not an administrator) navigating to the file that the AutomationTest.py is in and typing

```
pyinstaller AutomationTest.py
```

Comment: What happens when you open the **.exe** from the command line? It might give you more of a clue what went wrong.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Regarding the error finding `python`: In PyCharm you probably have a `venv` directory. To configure `python` in Powershell call `venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` (or `.bat` if you're using `cmd`)

Comment: Ethan N what is your code? You may be missing an important part of it that shows no issue until you try to convert it into exe.